# How can I get the maximum value of all the components in a vector?

Tags: c, vector, max

I just wrote a program that saves a 4-component vector entered by the user (using a function called `save_vector`) and prints it (using a function called `print_vector`). Also, it creates a new vector called `vabs` that has the same components but in absolute value (positive).

Now I am trying to find the maximum value in the `vabs` vector by using the function `maximum value`. However, I only get this result: `0.000000` even though I am entering non-zero components in the vector. Could you help me figure out what I am missing? Thank you! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_vector(int N,float * V);
void save_vector(int N,float * V);
void absolute_values(int N, float * V);
void maximum_value(int N, float * VABS);


int main(void)
{

    const int n=5;
    int i;
    float v[n],vabs[n];

    puts("Enter the 5 components of the vector:");
    save_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe vector is:");
    print_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe absolute vector is:");
    absolute_values(n, v);

    puts("\nThe maximum value is:");
    maximum_value(n, vabs);

    return 0;
}

void save_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%f",V+i);
}

void print_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %.2f ",*(V+i));
}

void absolute_values(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    float VABS[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        VABS[i]=((V[i]<0)?-V[i]:V[i]);
        printf(" %f", VABS[i]);
    }
}

void maximum_value(int N, float * VABS)
{
  int i;
  float maximum;
  maximum = VABS[0];

  for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  {
    if (VABS[i] > maximum)
    {
       maximum = VABS[i];
    }
  }
  printf(" %f", maximum);
}
```

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with yr debugger?

Comment: well , you use a vector called 'n' everywhere but then pass vabs to the max function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not working as intended because:

- You are passing an empty vector `vabs` to the function which should find the max_value.
- In the function that assigns the absolute values, your `VABS` vector is local, it will be lost as the function returns, you need to pass the `main` `vabs` vector to the function as an argument so that the changes can be saved and used to find the max value:

```
void absolute_values(int N, float *V, float *VABS) //pass vabs as argument
{
    int i;
    //float VABS[N]; this is local, it's lost when the function returns
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        VABS[i] = ((V[i] < 0) ? -V[i] : V[i]);
        printf(" %f", VABS[i]);
    }
}
```

And in main:

```
int main(void)
{  
    //...
    puts("\nThe absolute vector is:");
    absolute_values(n, v, vabs);

    puts("\nThe maximum value is:");
    maximum_value(n, vabs);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a [**running sample of the fixed code**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/HelplessAnimatedOutliner).

Comment: Thank you, @Anastaciu! Just added the declaration of `maxvalue` to my question. However, I still would need to know how to work with the components stored in `VABS` (which is not empty). That is the vector I want to use to find and print the max value from. Thank you!

Comment: @Henry, you were not passing the vector vabs to the absolute_values function so the changes were lost, I edited the answer with the solution and a running sample.

Comment: This is awesome @anastaciu. Thanks very much for all your help!!! :-)

Comment: @Henry, I'm glad I could help, your question is very clear, that helps pinpointing the issues.